# Java - How to change font/add border to only part of a JLabel

Tags: java, html, swing, jframe, jlabel

In this instance `die1` is an `Integer` that is derived from a calculation elsewhere. I want the value of `die1` to be visually differentiated with a border and/or larger text/different color. Is there a way to do this that does not involve having 2 separate `JLabels`? Thank you.

```
firstJLabel.setText("Die 1: " + die1);
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to do this that does not involve having 2 separate JLabels?

You can use HTML in a label:

```
firstJLabel.setText("<html><font color=\"red\">Die 1: </font>" + die1 + "</html>");
```

Or you could use a `JTextPane` and make it look like a label. It supports attributes:

```
JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
textPane.setBorder( null );
textPane.setOpaque( false );

SimpleAttributeSet green = new SimpleAttributeSet();
StyleConstants.setForeground(green, Color.GREEN);

//  Add some text

try
{
    StyledDocument doc = textPane.getStyledDocument();
    doc.insertString(0, die1, null);
    doc.insertString(0, "Die 1: ", green);
}
catch(Exception) {}
```